# It is possible to use array reduce concept from swift in objective c?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, reduce

I have this lines of code in Swift:

```
let graphPoints:[Int] = [4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 8, 3]

let average = graphPoints.reduce(0, combine: +) / graphPoints.count
```

It is possible to "translate" this lines of code in objective c code?

It's not very clear for me how reduce combine concept works. I read about it but still is unclear.

I took the code from this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/90693/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-2

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: what type does the `graphPoints` array contain?

Comment: Guess: `average = [graphView.graphPoints valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"]` (or maybe `@avg` instead of `@sum`).

Comment: array is: var graphPoints:[Int] = [4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 8, 3], contains int objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

let's say you have some `NSNumber`s stored in an `NSArray` you can use this KVC collection operator:

```
NSArray *someNumbers = @[@0, @1.1, @2, @3.4, @5, @6.7];
NSNumber *average = [someNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];
```

Answer (score 3):

For Objective-C, I would add the Higher-Order-Functions to this list of answers: https://github.com/fanpyi/Higher-Order-Functions

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef id (^ReduceBlock)(id accumulator,id item);
@interface NSArray (HigherOrderFunctions)
-(id)reduce:(id)initial combine:(ReduceBlock)combine;
@end

#import "NSArray+HigherOrderFunctions.h"
@implementation NSArray (HigherOrderFunctions)
-(id)reduce:(id)initial combine:(ReduceBlock)combine{
    id accumulator = initial;
    for (id item in self) {
        accumulator = combine(accumulator, item);
    }
    return accumulator;
}
@end
```

**example:**

```
   NSArray *numbers = @[@5,@7,@3,@8];
    NSNumber *sum = [numbers reduce:@0 combine:^id(id accumulator, id item) {
        return @([item intValue] + [accumulator intValue]);
    }];
    NSNumber *multiplier = [numbers reduce:@1 combine:^id(id accumulator, id item) {
        return @([item intValue] * [accumulator intValue]);
    }];
    NSLog(@"sum=%@,multiplier=%@",sum,multiplier);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `reduce` function is not standard in Objective-C. You can implement it as an extension of `NSArray` though.

In your case, you have an array of `Int` in Swift. You cannot have that in Objective-C, you need an array of `NSNumber`.

Here is an implementation of `reduce` that should work in your case:

```
@implementation NSArray (Helpers)

- (NSInteger)reduceInt:(NSInteger)initial combine:(NSInteger (^)(NSInteger acum, NSInteger element))block {
    if (!self) {
        return initial;
    }

    NSInteger acum = initial;
    for (id element in self) {
        if ([element isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            acum = block(acum, [(NSNumber *)element integerValue]);
        }
    }

    return acum;
}

@end
```

You can use it then with your array, something like this:

```
NSArray *a = @[@1, @2, @3];
NSInteger result = [a reduceInt:0 combine:^NSInteger(NSInteger acum, NSInteger element) {
    return acum + element;
}];
```

Comment: I think that `reduce` doesn't have much sense without generic types though.

Comment: @Sulthan Well, you can have an implementation of `reduce` with `id`s, that is general enough to use in your code. Of course, having generics would be better.

Comment: AFAICT, `if (!self)` check isn't necessary – it's an instance method, so this must be called on `self`. Thereby, `self` will _always_ be non-`nil`.

Answer (score 1):

how to translate reduce to ObjC (or better to say how to solve your "average problem" in Objective C) was perfectly answered by André Slotta. the swift reduce is much more than that. I will try to answer the second part of your question, how the concept works in swift

```
func reduce<T>(initial: T, @noescape combine: (T, Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> T
```

> Return the result
>   of repeatedly calling combine with an accumulated value initialized to
>   initial and each element of self, in turn, i.e. return
>   combine(combine(...combine(combine(initial, self[0]),
>   self[1]),...self[count-2]), self[count-1]).

```
let arr: Array<Int> = [1,2,3,4,5]
let sum = arr.reduce(0) { (sum, i) -> Int in
    return sum + i
}
print(sum) // 15

// this is an quasi equivalent of
var sum1 = 0 // ..... reduce(0)....
arr.forEach { (elementValue) -> Void in
    sum1 = sum1 + elementValue   // ...{ return sum + i }
}
print(sum1) // 15 reduce function will return accumulated inital value

// reduce is part of SequenceType protocol, that is why

let arr1 = ["H","e","l","l","o"," ","w","o","r","l","d"]
let str = arr1.reduce("") { (str, s) -> String in
    str + s
}
// works the same way
print(str) // "Hello world"

// let have a litle bit more complex example, to see how powerful, useful and easy to use reduce can be
let dict = arr1.reduce([:]) { (var dict, s) -> Dictionary<Int,String> in
    let i = dict.count
    dict.updateValue(s, forKey: i+1)
    return dict
}
print(dict) // [11: "d", 10: "l", 2: "e", 4: "l", 9: "r", 5: "o", 6: " ", 7: "w", 3: "l", 1: "H", 8: "o"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an NSArray extension

```
- (NSInteger)reduceStart:(NSInteger)start combine:(NSInteger(^)(NSInteger x, NSInteger y))combine {
    for (NSNumber* n in self) {
        if ([n isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            start = combine (start, n.integerValue);
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

fix all mistakes that I made, and that's it. Just less flexible than Swift.